# Using Excel Forms and Data Validation, Rows Before error contents deleted

Tags: excel, forms, validation

I am using the Excel forms feature that allows you to enter data in a table using a form. I also have data validation on every column to ensure proper data. When there is an error in one cell it deletes all the contents for the cells earlier in the row.

For example, I have entered data in cells A2:G2, but put an improper value in H2. In the form it will still show that cells A2:G2 have values but once I correct H2 and submit, A2:G2 is all blank.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?